# Merge two lists, Ruby on Rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby

I have two lists:

```
@content_old = Content.where("state = ?", "old").order('ctr DESC')
@content_new = Content.where("state = ?", "new").order('RAND()')
```

I want merge these lists, but second list add to first list not in the end. I want "random merge", ie each element of second list merges with first list in RANDOM position

The items from the first collection are supposed to preserve their relative order.

Comment: FYI: Only use variable interpolation when you need an operator that isn't `=`. In this case, use `state: 'new'` and `state: 'old'`.

Comment: Is `ctr` an integer?

Comment: @Stefan yes, ctr integer

Comment: does the second list have `ctr` too ? you could just do a single order with ctr

Comment: No, second list have't ctr. ctr have only where(state: 'old')

Comment: what's the minimum and maximum value of ctr?

Answer (score 3):

Why not just do one query

```
Content.where(state: ['old','new']).order('RAND()')
```

You want it in a random order either ways, so why sort and sort then 'unsort'

---

Ok here's my second thoughts according to the new info, the trick is to fill the second list with random ctr, then do the sorting once without bothering about the merge

```
content_old = Content.where(state: 'old')
content_new = Content.select('*, RAND() as ctr').where(state: 'new')
@random_content = (content_old+content_new).sort_by(&:ctr).reverse
```

This would work if you don't really need the ctr value, because it would add random values to some records in the memory only, it would be safe in the database, if you want to be extra cautious you could call `readonly` like this:

```
content_new = Content.readonly.select('*, RAND() as ctr').where(state: 'new')
```

To customize the range of `RAND()` you could read the [doc page](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en/mathematical-functions.html#function_rand), it has a function to show how to set `RAND()`'s start and end

Comment: The items from the first collection are supposed to preserve their relative order.

Comment: ah ok i see, could you add that in the question because it wasn't clear

Comment: This only works if the fixed `ctr` values are evenly distributed and if all `ctr` values are different (you can't generate a random value that's in-between `2` and `2`).

Comment: The OP didn't really provide any info about the values range, so I can't really tell if this would suit him or not, I've added question about that in the comments, and i didn't get any answers, so as far as I know right now, yea you're right, I was just trying to tell him the idea and he should modify it to suit him

Answer (score 1):

Probably not very efficient for large arrays, but you could insert each item from the "new" array at a random position into the (sorted) "old" array. Something like:

```
sorted = Content.where(state: 'old').order('ctr DESC').to_a
others = Content.where(state: 'new')

others.each { |item| sorted.insert(rand(0..sorted.size), item) }
```

Here's an example with actual data:

```
10.times do
  sorted = (1..10).to_a
  others = %i(foo bar baz)
  others.each { |item| sorted.insert(rand(0..sorted.size), item) }
  p sorted
end
```

Output:

```
[:bar, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, :foo, 8, 9, 10, :baz]
[1, 2, :bar, 3, 4, :baz, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 10, :foo]
[1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, :foo, :bar, 7, 8, 9, :baz, 10]
[1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, :foo, :bar, 7, 8, :baz, 9, 10]
[1, 2, 3, 4, :foo, 5, :baz, 6, 7, :bar, 8, 9, 10]
[1, :baz, 2, 3, 4, 5, :foo, 6, 7, 8, :bar, 9, 10]
[:foo, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, :bar, :baz, 6, 7, 8, 9, 10]
[1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, :baz, :bar, 8, 9, :foo, 10]
[1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, :bar, :foo, :baz, 7, 8, 9, 10]
[1, 2, 3, 4, 5, :bar, 6, :foo, 7, 8, 9, 10, :baz]
```

Comment: @AlexIvanov the elements from `others` are inserted into the `sorted` array and that becomes the result. So yes, the result (`sorted`) is an array.